# ExpressionTree Debugger Visualizer And VS2010

Tags: lambda, expression

I am having trouble getting the old VS2008 ExpressionTree deubgger visualizer sample which is available here : http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Visual-Studio-2008-C-d295cdba

Working with VS2010.

I understand that sample was built for an older version of .NET, and as such needs to be recompiled using the latest VS2010 DebuggerVisualizers.dll.

So here is what I have done

1. Downloaded VS2008 samples from link above :
   http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Visual-Studio-2008-C-d295cdba
2. Opened project in VS2010
3. Changed the projects to target .NET4.0
4. Changed the references to point to
   this location for the DebuggerVisualizers.dll :     C:\Program Files
   (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers.dll
5. Built the projects, checked that I can actually visualize an expression tree. All works fine in modified standalone project from samples
6. Copied the ExpressionTreeVisualizer.dll to the following locations

   ...\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Visualizers
    ...\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers

But I can't see the debugger visualizer in VS2010 at all.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I managed to find out what was going on here. Which is that you MUST put a separate Assembly level Attribute for the Debugger Visualizer for each type you wish it to work with.

Unfortunately it does not seem clever enough for it to know that by walking the inheritance tree. So I did everything about but modified the source code to include the following attributes in the class "ExpressionTreeVisualizer" from the sample code

```
[assembly: DebuggerVisualizer(typeof(ExpressionTreeVisualizerForVisualStudio2010), typeof(ExpressionTreeVisualizerObjectSource), 
    Target = typeof(Expression), Description = "Expression Tree Visualizer")]
[assembly: DebuggerVisualizer(typeof(ExpressionTreeVisualizerForVisualStudio2010), typeof(ExpressionTreeVisualizerObjectSource), 
    Target = typeof(BinaryExpression), Description = "Expression Tree Visualizer")]
[assembly: DebuggerVisualizer(typeof(ExpressionTreeVisualizerForVisualStudio2010), typeof(ExpressionTreeVisualizerObjectSource), 
    Target = typeof(BlockExpression), Description = "Expression Tree Visualizer")]
[assembly: DebuggerVisualizer(typeof(ExpressionTreeVisualizerForVisualStudio2010), typeof(ExpressionTreeVisualizerObjectSource), 
    Target = typeof(ConditionalExpression), Description = "Expression Tree Visualizer")]
[assembly: DebuggerVisualizer(typeof(ExpressionTreeVisualizerForVisualStudio2010), typeof(ExpressionTreeVisualizerObjectSource), 
    Target = typeof(ConstantExpression), Description = "Expression Tree Visualizer")]
[assembly: DebuggerVisualizer(typeof(ExpressionTreeVisualizerForVisualStudio2010), typeof(ExpressionTreeVisualizerObjectSource), 
    Target = typeof(DebugInfoExpression), Description = "Expression Tree Visualizer")]
[assembly: DebuggerVisualizer(typeof(ExpressionTreeVisualizerForVisualStudio2010), typeof(ExpressionTreeVisualizerObjectSource), 
    Target = typeof(DefaultExpression), Description = "Expression Tree Visualizer")]
[assembly: DebuggerVisualizer(typeof(ExpressionTreeVisualizerForVisualStudio2010), typeof(ExpressionTreeVisualizerObjectSource), 
    Target = typeof(DynamicExpression), Description = "Expression Tree Visualizer")]
[assembly: DebuggerVisualizer(typeof(ExpressionTreeVisualizerForVisualStudio2010), typeof(ExpressionTreeVisualizerObjectSource), 
    Target = typeof(GotoExpression), Description = "Expression Tree Visualizer")]
[assembly: DebuggerVisualizer(typeof(ExpressionTreeVisualizerForVisualStudio2010), typeof(ExpressionTreeVisualizerObjectSource), 
    Target = typeof(IndexExpression), Description = "Expression Tree Visualizer")]
[assembly: DebuggerVisualizer(typeof(ExpressionTreeVisualizerForVisualStudio2010), typeof(ExpressionTreeVisualizerObjectSource), 
    Target = typeof(InvocationExpression), Description = "Expression Tree Visualizer")]
[assembly: DebuggerVisualizer(typeof(ExpressionTreeVisualizerForVisualStudio2010), typeof(ExpressionTreeVisualizerObjectSource), 
    Target = typeof(LabelExpression), Description = "Expression Tree Visualizer")]
[assembly: DebuggerVisualizer(typeof(ExpressionTreeVisualizerForVisualStudio2010), typeof(ExpressionTreeVisualizerObjectSource), 
    Target = typeof(LambdaExpression), Description = "Expression Tree Visualizer")]
[assembly: DebuggerVisualizer(typeof(ExpressionTreeVisualizerForVisualStudio2010), typeof(ExpressionTreeVisualizerObjectSource), 
    Target = typeof(ListInitExpression), Description = "Expression Tree Visualizer")]
[assembly: DebuggerVisualizer(typeof(ExpressionTreeVisualizerForVisualStudio2010), typeof(ExpressionTreeVisualizerObjectSource), 
    Target = typeof(LoopExpression), Description = "Expression Tree Visualizer")]
[assembly: DebuggerVisualizer(typeof(ExpressionTreeVisualizerForVisualStudio2010), typeof(ExpressionTreeVisualizerObjectSource), 
    Target = typeof(MemberExpression), Description = "Expression Tree Visualizer")]
[assembly: DebuggerVisualizer(typeof(ExpressionTreeVisualizerForVisualStudio2010), typeof(ExpressionTreeVisualizerObjectSource), 
    Target = typeof(MemberInitExpression), Description = "Expression Tree Visualizer")]
[assembly: DebuggerVisualizer(typeof(ExpressionTreeVisualizerForVisualStudio2010), typeof(ExpressionTreeVisualizerObjectSource), 
    Target = typeof(MethodCallExpression), Description = "Expression Tree Visualizer")]
[assembly: DebuggerVisualizer(typeof(ExpressionTreeVisualizerForVisualStudio2010), typeof(ExpressionTreeVisualizerObjectSource), 
    Target = typeof(NewArrayExpression), Description = "Expression Tree Visualizer")]
[assembly: DebuggerVisualizer(typeof(ExpressionTreeVisualizerForVisualStudio2010), typeof(ExpressionTreeVisualizerObjectSource), 
    Target = typeof(NewExpression), Description = "Expression Tree Visualizer")]
[assembly: DebuggerVisualizer(typeof(ExpressionTreeVisualizerForVisualStudio2010), typeof(ExpressionTreeVisualizerObjectSource), 
    Target = typeof(ParameterExpression), Description = "Expression Tree Visualizer")]
[assembly: DebuggerVisualizer(typeof(ExpressionTreeVisualizerForVisualStudio2010), typeof(ExpressionTreeVisualizerObjectSource), 
    Target = typeof(RuntimeVariablesExpression), Description = "Expression Tree Visualizer")]
[assembly: DebuggerVisualizer(typeof(ExpressionTreeVisualizerForVisualStudio2010), typeof(ExpressionTreeVisualizerObjectSource), 
    Target = typeof(SwitchExpression), Description = "Expression Tree Visualizer")]
[assembly: DebuggerVisualizer(typeof(ExpressionTreeVisualizerForVisualStudio2010), typeof(ExpressionTreeVisualizerObjectSource), 
    Target = typeof(TryExpression), Description = "Expression Tree Visualizer")]
[assembly: DebuggerVisualizer(typeof(ExpressionTreeVisualizerForVisualStudio2010), typeof(ExpressionTreeVisualizerObjectSource), 
    Target = typeof(TypeBinaryExpression), Description = "Expression Tree Visualizer")]
[assembly: DebuggerVisualizer(typeof(ExpressionTreeVisualizerForVisualStudio2010), typeof(ExpressionTreeVisualizerObjectSource), 
    Target = typeof(UnaryExpression), Description = "Expression Tree Visualizer")]
```

Comment: This was worth it just for the complete list of expression types.

Comment: Note that currently (tested in VS 2017 and VS 2019) you only need to apply the attribute with the `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression` type.

Comment: yay that makes things easier

Comment: NB You may be interested in the [debugging visualizer I've written for expression trees](https://github.com/zspitz/ExpressionTreeVisualizer).